# Fixed toolbars not working when iframe is in content

Tags: jquery-mobile

I copied the google maps example out of the jquerymobile-docs. I need fixed toolbars (header and footer), but when I include the iframe-popup in the content, then the toolsbars are scrolling and jumping back on the right position. It works well in desktop browsers but not on iPhone 5.

This is the popup which causes the problems:

```html
<div id="popupMap" class="popupMap" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right"></a>
    <iframe id="mapIframe" src="http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/popup/map.html" width="480" height="320"></iframe>
</div>
```

I've created a full demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A2TeY/)

Please copy the code and run it on iPhone to see what I mean. Then remove the popup-code (iframe) and compare the results.

Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: try to put the popup div out of your dara-role=content, and place it into your data-role page div

Comment: Already tried, without success. I've also tried iScroll, but this also does not work.